# Inefiecient code on loops. 10000000 loop challenge.

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, memory-efficient

I don't know how to make my code more efficient. It completes the examples, but it will time out when it tackles the big array.

I ask you for some advice for performance on loops, or if you can tell me where my error is. If my approach is completely wrong don't give me the answer please.

What i have to do:
 Given a list of integers and a single sum value, return the first two values (parse from the left please) in order of appearance that add up to form the sum.

---

Examples:

sum_pairs([11, 3, 7, 5], 10) => [3, 7]

---

sum_pairs([4, 3, 2, 3, 4],  6)=>[2, 4],[3, 3],[2, 4]
 (indices:0,2|1,3|2,4)=>

- entire pair is earlier, and therefore is the correct answer===[2, 4]

---

sum_pairs([0, 0, -2, 3], 2)
   there are no pairs of values that can be added to produce 2.
== None/nil/undefined (Based on the language)

---

sum_pairs([10, 5, 2, 3, 7, 5],10)=>[5, 5][3, 7]
        --------------------1------------5
                --------------------------3--4
indicies:(1,5|3,4)

- entire pair is earlier, and therefore is the correct answer
  == [3, 7]

---

My attemt:

```
var sum_pairs=function(ints, s){
    for(t=1; t <=ints.length-1;t++){
    for(i=0; i <=ints.length-t-1;i++){
        if(ints[i]+ints[i+t]===s){
            return [ints[i],ints[i+t]];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds more like a question for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Alnitak indeed, this can be found there; it's a Codewars question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a duplicate of a codereview.stackexchange.com question

Comment: I appreciate that the OP didn't want to be given the answer, but this problem in particular calls for a solution that's so simple that a hint is hard to provide without giving the whole thing away.

Comment: One hint Rman: to return an answer, there's no need to find *all* the pairs. You just need to find one.

Comment: A second hint: You can do this with only one loop, but it requires you to trade memory for time.